# MissingServletRequestParameterException while hitting a url with input parameters from batch file

Tags: batch-file, url, exception

I am trying to hit a url

```
start http://localhost:8080/startViewerWithInput?val1=25db8e44-b678-48cc-81a5-0000001eba28&val2=-2522169635265019118
```

This works fine from web browser

but when I am trying to put it in batch file

my application gives error like

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'val2' is not present

my code looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startViewerWithInput", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String startViewerWithUserInput(@RequestParam(value = "val1",required = true) String val1, @RequestParam(value = "val2", required = true) String val2)
```

> throws TimeoutException, ParseException {}

I know I am doing something stupid with the URL when I am putting them in batch. Please help me.

Comment: Presumably cmd is breaking your url while parsing the line. Either double quote the URL `start "" "http://localhost:8080/startViewerWithInput?val1=25db8e44-b678-48cc-81a5-0000001eba28&val2=-2522169635265019118"` or escape the equal signs `^=` with a caret `http://localhost:8080/startViewerWithInput?val1^=25db8e44-b678-48cc-81a5-0000001eba28&val2^=-2522169635265019118`

Comment: I tried start "" "http://localhost:8080/startViewerWithInput?val1=25db8e44-b6‌​78-48cc-81a5-0000001‌​eba28&val2=-25221696‌​35265019118" worked like a charm . @LotPings you are a savior  :)